# Emplois pronominaux inusités avec inanimés chez certains auteurs du nord de la France ?

Tags: sens, verbes-pronominaux, régionalismes

> *Bouger.*
>   Ce Verbe ne veut point régir de Nom : il est abſolument neutre. Par
>   exemple *ils ne bougèrent point* ; & non pas, *ils ne ſe bougèrent
>   point*, comme a écrit M. de Malherbe en ſa traduction de *Tite-Live* [[ceci](https://books.google.com/books?id=b0pfW1Co0GgC&lpg&pg=PA422#v=onepage) ?] .
>   Cela eſt du pays de Normandie.
>
> [ [*Nouvelles remarques de M. de Vaugelas sur la langue française*
>   (posthume)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=s4BnBXZfl4oC&dq&pg=PA16) , Claude Favre de Vaugelas ]

*Se bouger* est *rare* en dehors de la *langue parlée familière*, même si anciennement la forme pronominale était plus courante que la forme transitive sans pronom ne l'est devenue au 17<sup>e</sup>. (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 781). On avait identifié qu'avec le verbe *remuer*, on pouvait dire de quelqu'un qu'il *remuait* ou *se remuait* tout le temps, mais que sous l'effet du vent, on n'acceptait seulement que les feuilles *remuassent*. On a aussi remarqué la propension de certains auteurs du nord de la France a utiliser des constructions pronominales particulières avec des inanimés, parfois sans valeur passive, dit-on. Et on donne en particulier ces exemples du 19<sup>e</sup> :

> (1) — Sa robe de lin, alourdie par les grelots qui s'alternaient sur ses
>   talons avec des pommes d'émeraude. ([Flaubert](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustave_Flaubert))
>  (2) — Les jupes se bouffaient.(Flaubert)
>   (3) — Des primevères s'étaient écloses. (Flaubert)
>  (4) — Quoiqu'il eut bien, de temps à
>   autre, quelque boulette de papier lancée d'un bec de plume qui vînt
>   s'éclabousser sur sa figure. (Flaubert)
>  (5) — Les rayons du soleil couchant
>   traversaient en oblique les persiennes closes et s'éclaboussaient sur
>   les assiettes et les plats. ([La Varende](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_La_Varende))

---

- Qu'est-ce que ces auteurs veulent communiquer, avec ces emplois
  pronominaux, que l'emploi non pronominal réaliserait différemment ici, en
  termes de sens, de registre, de style etc. ?
- Pourquoi cet usage se manifeste-t-il encore chez ces auteurs du nord
  de la France bien longtemps après qu'il ne soit devenu
  moins usité ? Les deux premiers exemples de Flaubert sont-ils vraiment inusités aujourd'hui ?
- Généralement, y a-t-il une raison pour laquelle on employait davantage de formes pronominales en Normandie (sur quoi repose ce *normandisme*) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grevisse dans Le Bon usage (14e ed., §781) discute de cette construction, qu'il appelle "pronominal inanimé":

> Plus encore que pour les pronominaux animés, le pronom conjoint des inanimés s'analyse difficilement du point de vue logique: il ne peut guère être considéré comme un objet direct [i.e. puisque les verbe en question n'ont souvent pas de forme transitive]. par conséquent, il fait preuve d'une instabilité particulière. Un certain nombre de verbes peuvent être pronominaux ou non sans que le sens en soit modifié.

De citer dans cette catégorie: *augmenter, enfler, enfoncer, gonfler, grossir, mourir, noircir, pourrir, refroidir, rétrécir*...

Il ajoute d'ailleurs, ce qui est tout à fait pertinent en ce qui concerne tes exemples:

> Les écrivains emploient des pronominaux inanimés étrangers à la langue ordinaire (parfois sans valeur passive). [...] Parfois la construction s'écarte fort de l'usage ordinaire.

Parmi les exemples qu'il cite ici? *éclabousser* et *éclore*!

Il note aussi que pour plusieurs verbes, l'usage pronominal tend à se perdre dans l'usage contemporain (notamment *faner*, *empirer*, *briser*).

Finalement, dans le cas de *bouger*, Grevisse note que l'usage transitif de ce verbe est assez tardif, et avant le 17e siècle, on trouvait *se bouger* plus fréquemment que *bouger [qqch]*. D'où la remarque de Vaugelas, notoirement rébarbatif à toute nouveauté langagière, qui écrit justement à l'époque où l'usage transitif de ce verbe se répand!

---

**En résumé**, le français permet d'employer les verbes intransitif dans des constructions pronominale sans que le sens n'en soit affecté lorsque le sujet est inanimé. C'est un construction d'un style plutôt relevé qui semble sur la pente descendante. Cette construction s'étend parfois aux animés et dans certains cas en est venue à complètement remplacer la construction intransitive d'origine (par ex. pour *écrouler*).

Answer (score 1):

*Réponse très subjective :*

> Qu'est-ce qu'on fait ? On se bouge ? Y s'remue pas beaucoup çui-là

... ne sont pas rares en langage familier, comme vous le faites remarquer, et leurs emplois est courant un peu partout dans l’hexagone.

> - Ils ne bougèrent point : ils ne firent aucun mouvement
> - Il ne se bougèrent point : ils décidèrent de ne pas bouger.

Les tournure que l'on n'emploie plus de nos jours :

> - Les jupes se bouffaient.(Flaubert)

*Bouffer* étant l'argot de *manger*, on entendrait : Elles se *mangeaient* (entre elles) ?

> - Des primevères s'étaient écloses. (Flaubert)

Telles quelles, cela supposerait une intention de ces fleurs hors des cycles normaux de la nature.

> - ... qui s'alternaient sur ses talons ... / ... s'éclabousser sur sa figure.

... indique un mouvement intentionnel réussi. Le déplacement de l'intention de l'acteur réel, sur l'objet cité intensifie le résultat.
Le fait de signifier que le résultat se personnifie sur le lieu du résultat enferme ce lieu dans une singularité active, et, avec

> - s'éclaboussaient sur les assiettes et les plats.

un anthropomorphisme poétique apparaît.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Seuls les deux derniers des cinq exemples sont encore accessibles aux oreilles contemporaines, et peuvent être employées dans des expressions poétiques sans passer pour de la pédanterie, sinon on doit pouvoir les utiliser lorsque l'on sollicite des académiciens bien bien âgés, des concours et exercices littéraires : "À la façon de G. Flaubert, *Décrivez une goutte de rosée sur une lame de couteau*, sans employer aucun des termes de l'énoncée, en deux pages, soit sept cents mots minimum"... certains profs le donnait comme exercice à leur meilleur élève (au singulier).

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Basé sur deux fois vingt-cinq lignes de quinze mots, ceux qui écrivent large doivent pouvoir faire rentrer l'exercices sur deux pages, les autres peuvent compléter jusqu'à huit-cent ou plus... Il s'agit bien des phrases (4) et (5) ; c'est peut-être un  réflexe personnel, mais la (3) me gène, peut-être un antique reste des *Sciences Naturelles* lycéennes ?

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Ce qui me gène aussi dans la phrase (3), c'est sa brièveté, le manque de contexte donne une préciosité un peu boursouflée à cette formulation littéraire ; en revanche si c'est un vers de huit pieds... pourquoi pas : on évoque le temps (la durée, cela s'est passé récemment comme le suggère le `s'`, et, le printemps, période de floraison) sans en écrire un mot.